# OOM in second round of cross-validation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, gpu, cross-validation

**What I need help with / What I was wondering**
I am performing cross-validation using the keras API, and have put all the code to perform one round of CV into a single function. The first round of CV works, but then upon the second round, I get an OOM error upon trying to build the next model.

- Why is this happening?
- How do I properly do this type of CV from a single python process?
- Is there a way to completely flush the GPU/TPU memory to control things like memory fragmentation?

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def run_fold_training(k_fold, num_folds, batch_size):
    #clear graph
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    #try to get tpu or else gpu
    try:
        tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
        print('Device:', tpu.master())
        tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
        tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
        strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
    except:
        strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()
    print('Number of replicas:', strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
    with strategy.scope():
        # make k-fold dataset
        ds = build_dataset()
        train_ds = ds.enumerate().filter(
            lambda i, ds, num_folds=num_folds, k_fold=k_fold: i % num_folds != k_fold).map(
            lambda i, ds: ds).batch(batch_size)
        test_ds = ds.enumerate().filter(
            lambda i, ds, num_folds=num_folds, k_fold=k_fold: i % num_folds == k_fold).map(
            lambda i, ds: ds).batch(batch_size)
        # make, train, evaluate model
        model = MyModel(**model_kwargs)
        model.compile(**compile_kwargs)
        model.fit(train_ds, epochs=25)
        results = model.evaluate(test_ds, return_dict=True)

    return results["score"]

num_folds = 5
batch_size = 8
cv_loss = sum([run_fold_training(k, num_folds, batch_size) for k in range(num_folds)]) / num_folds
print(f"Final {num_folds}-fold cross validation score is: {cv_loss}")
```

**What I've tried so far**
I'm clearing the keras backend at the start of the CV round and I'm also creating a new distribute strategy scope per round. I've already tried batch sizes of [1,2,4,8]. For all batchsizes it does one round fine, but gives OOM at the start of the next round.

**It would be nice if...**
It would be great it there was access to lower level control over memory management. This could be in tiers of complexity. Like, simplest case would be a function that frees all device memory related to a certain graph. In TF1 I would have just made a new session per CV round, and this wouldn't be a problem.

**Environment information**
(if applicable)

- Operating System: ubuntu 18.04
- Python version: 3.8
- Docker: `tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.1-gpu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was discovered by a friend. If there are references to graph ops/variables created outside the `run_fold_training` function then the `clear_session` will not completely work. The solution is to make sure that entire new graph is created after the `clear_session`. E.g. don't reuse optimizers, etc.